# Collapse bootstrap 3 multilevel submenu & change active state when submenu is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown menu in bootstrap 3, with a custom submenu. I am trying to add the same behavior as the original dropdown. Basically to be able to click the submenu dropdown and close it as well, right now it just opens but when you try to close it by clicking the same link it does not do anything.

I have tried to do this with collapse but I had no success, I have set up a js fiddle to show you what I have so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/29TYj/

This .js code allows me to have multiple dropdown menus without adding custom classes, I have been trying to modify this with no success.

```
$('.dropdown-submenu').click(function(){
  $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').css('display','block');
  return false;
});
```

And like I said I attempted to do this using collapse inside the markup, but had no success.

I am also working on changing the submenu active class (when you hover over drop 1 and move into the submenu drop 1 should be white text on an orange bg) but I cannot figure out the correct order of the nested classes if anyone can give me a hint on that as well.

---

***UPDATE:***

Okay, I was able to do what I need with the submenu by changing my javascript to:

```
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu > li > a.trigger").on("click",function(e){
        var current=$(this).next();
        current.toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Also changing the submenu link in the mark up to contain the trigger class:

```
<a class="trigger">One Page Versions <span class="ion-ios7-arrow-right submenu-arrow"></span></a>
```

Here is an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/29TYj/2/

I am still trying to find the correct active class for the sub menu if someone can help with that. I did the same thing with the navbar links, for example I used this class to keep the link highlighted:

```
.nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:hover, .nav .open > a:focus {
    background-color: #ff7454 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, here is a simple jQuery solution. Just add this code to your script:

```
//toggles the .open class on the element to highlight it
$(".dropdown-submenu > a.trigger").on("click", function(e){
    var parent = $(this).parent('.dropdown-submenu');
    parent.toggleClass('open');
});
//Removes the added class .open if the user clicks on the main navigation to close it
$(".dropdown > a").on("click",function(e){
    $(".dropdown-submenu").removeClass('open');
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29TYj/3/)